# Responsive Menu with Semantic UI React

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

With Semantic UI React I'm having trouble in creating a responsive navigation menu.

Here's normal desktop view:

[image]

and then here's the mobile view, in which the top right side of the menu is out of view:

[image]

Here's the code for navigation menu:

```
const MenuNav = props => {
  const logout = () => {
    props.logout();
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  };

  return (
    <Menu>
      <Container>
        <Menu.Item header>
          <Image
            src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/all-vintage-search-logo.png`}
            href="https://www.allvintagesearch.com"
            alt="All Vintage Search"
            style={{ width: "auto", maxWidth: "300px", overflow: "hidden" }}
          />
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Menu position="right">
          {props.loggedUser.id !== undefined ? (
            <>
              <Menu.Item link>
                <Link to="/favorites">My Favorites</Link>
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item link>
                <span>
                  <em>Hi {props.loggedUser.firstName} you're logged in!</em>{" "}
                  <Button size="mini" onClick={logout}>
                    logout
                  </Button>
                </span>
              </Menu.Item>
            </>
          ) : (
            <MenuItem>
              <Link to="/login">login</Link>
            </MenuItem>
          )}
        </Menu.Menu>
      </Container>
    </Menu>
  );
};
```

I've tried playing around with the image, and absent making it extremely tiny, i can't figure out how to get the navigation menu to appear responsive.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it help you: https://codesandbox.io/s/325y47xk36 I did'nt know - is it a right way for Semantic-ui-react, or not. But it works fine))

Answer (score 0):

Semantic-UI is probably the only Modern UI that does not offer Responsive Navigation Bar. This NPM package: [dna-responsive-nav](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dna-responsive-nav) could fix this limitation.